# Getter-function for derived class in derived class, when using pointer to base class

Tags: c++, class

I have two abstract base classes, `class_data` and `BaseClass`, with derived classes `overridden_class_data : public class_data` and `DerivedClass : public BaseClass`:

```
class class_data{
public:
    int val_a = 0;
    double val_b = 0.;
};

class overridden_class_data : public class_data{
public:
    int val_c = 0.;
};    

class BaseClass{
public:
    BaseClass(){};

    virtual void print_data() = 0;
    virtual class_data *get_local_data() = 0;

    class_data local_class_data;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
    DerivedClass(){
        local_class_data.val_a = 10;
        local_class_data.val_b = 100.;
        local_class_data.val_c = 14;
    };

    void print_data() override{
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }

    class_data * get_local_data() override {
        return &local_class_data;
    }

    overridden_class_data local_class_data;
};
```

Now, in external functions, I would like to use the base class pointer, while still transferring the derived class to the function (such that I can use the same function for several derived classes). In order to access the class variable `local_class_data`, I need a getter-function, else the class variable of the base class will be accessed. Here I wanted to use the same approach, i.e. use a pointer of the base class, while returning the derived class. Unfortunately, that does not work, and the line

```
std::cout << class_pointer->get_local_data()->val_c << '\n';
```

results in a compilation error

```
main.cc: In function ‘void test_func(BaseClass*)’:
main.cc:52:51: error: ‘class class_data’ has no member named ‘val_c’; did you mean ‘val_a’?
   52 |     std::cout << class_pointer->get_local_data()->val_c << '\n';
```

after the compiler still assumes that I am pointing to the class `BaseClass` (containing `class_data`) and not to the class `DerivedClass` containing `overridden_class_data`.
Is there a way I could solve my problem, while retaining the advantages of having an abstract base class?

Comment: You can downcast with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @n314159: Within the function? I then would need knowledge about the class I put into the function, which I do not have (due to using a BaseClass-pointer)

Comment: You already have the knowledge that the `class_pointer->get_local_data()` has type `overriden_class_data` otherwise it would make no sense to try and get `val_c` of it. Actually, you can even use static_cast since you seem to have perfect knowledge that this is the case.